# Java regex to remove all trailing numbers?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove any numbers from the end of a string, for example:

```
"TestUser12324" -> "TestUser"
"User2Allow555" -> "User2Allow"
"AnotherUser" -> "AnotherUser"
"Test123" -> "Test"
```

etc.

Anyone know how to do this with a regular expression in Java?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This should work for the Java String class, where myString contains the username:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\d*$", "");
```

This should match any number of trailing digit characters (0-9) that come at the end of the string and replace them with an empty string.

.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the value is in a string, s:

```
    s = s.replaceAll("[0-9]*$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct expression:

```
(.+[^0-9])\d*$
```

Comment: If the string is "Another1Userwee a8 8 8" , then what's the regex to remove all the trailing numbers so that output would come as "Another1Userwee a"