# Java Delete Everything But Something

Tags: java

Here's some code:

```
    String cakes = "I like to eat ice cream sandwiches at night";
    cakes = cakes.replace("ice cream", "");
    System.out.println(cakes);
```

This would delete ice cream. Cool. But what I would like is:

```
    String cakes = "I like to eat ice cream sandwiches at night";
    cakes = "ice" thru "sandwiches";
    System.out.println(cakes);
```

What that made up operation would do is delete everything except the letters between ice and sandwiches, making string cakes "ice cream sandwiches". Is that possible at all?

**EDIT:** I have a new code:

```
    String cakes = "I like to eat ice cream sandwiches at night";
    String ice = "ice";
    String sandwiches = "sandwiches";
    cakes = cakes.substring(cakes.indexOf(ice),cakes.indexOf(sandwiches)+sandwiches.length());

    System.out.println(cakes);
```

This works, but there's a problem: for some values of cake (e.g. html code of a website), I get an error:

```
          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -number
          at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
          at package.cclass.main(cat.java:31)
```

Comment: Use a regex-based replace(First) (hint hint)? Remember: the API docs are your friend. (Usually.)

Comment: Or a simple indexOf and sub string? Please show evidence of at least *some* effort.

Comment: Regular expressions. "ice(.*)cream" (or whatever regex fits your needs)

Comment: I tried deleting "I like to eat" and "sandwiches at night" with .replace. However, I want to make an application which that would not be useful.

Comment: I would just do indexOf on both and do a substring between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String ice = "ice";
String sandwiches = "sandwiches";
cakes = cakes.substring(cakes.indexOf(ice),cakes.indexOf(sandwiches)+sandwiches.length());
```

Comment: great, but if I have a big string (eg a log .txt document) It says:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -99

Comment: :( Stack overflow only allows 600 characters, so no. If I try putting in small strings, (eg "I'm a ice cool sandwhich string!") It works, but not if its a longer one (eg that 150 times)

Comment: I mean put that content in your question edit. Thereafter you may remove it.

Comment: @user1797443: Best Guess i can make is that In that big String you either don't have "ice" word or "sandwich" word. Make sure that both words are existing in that String.

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions come to mind for this.

This post has an example of just using a regex in Java: [Java regex to remove all trailing numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375466/java-regex-to-remove-all-trailing-numbers)

In this case, the expression would be something like: `"ice.*sandwiches"`

**Edit:** I thought we were removing those words. My mistake. Here's some code that should do more what you're looking for.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ice.*sandwiches");
Matcher m = p.matcher("I like to eat ice cream sandwiches at night");
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: If you mean cakes = cakes.replaceAll("\\ice*sandwich", "");, that gives tons of errors

Comment: How did you get "\\ice*sandwich"? This answer clearly gives you "ice.*sandwiches" so try cakes = cakes.replaceAll("ice.*sandwiches", "");

Comment: That does not work either Pshemo. That just removes ice cream sandwiches

Comment: @user1797443: I actually misread your original question. I thought you wanted to remove those characters!

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions or just String.indexOf() such as.

```
String wordOne = "ice";
String wordTwo = "sandwiches";

startIndex = cakes.indexOf(wordOne);
endIndex = cakes.indexOf(wordTwo) + wordTwo.length();

String result = cakes.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```